# app crashes on first run API 26

Tags: java, android, database

I created an app with database in assets folder . I wrote a code to copy database to sdcard and of course for android 6 + it needs run time permission. My problem : App copies database before asking for permission so for the first time app crashes but permission window is on screen and if you allow it on second run app works like charm . Please help me to solve this issue .

Here's my code :

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

public static Context context;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
ImageView hamburger;
SQLiteDatabase database;
String destPath;

public static ArrayList<Structure> list = new ArrayList<Structure>();
public static ArrayList<Structure> favorite = new ArrayList<Structure>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_activity_main);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){


        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this
                    , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            ,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                    , 1);

        }else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this
                    , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            ,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                    , 1);

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You grandet 
earlier",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }





    try {
        destPath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
        File file = new File(destPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("md_book.db"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/md_book.db"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    context = getApplicationContext();
    setTabOption();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    hamburger = findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
    hamburger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });




    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.exit) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);

                alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
which) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.show();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    selectList();
    selectFavorite();


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length >= 2 && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access granted", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}


private void setTabOption() {
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
context));
    TabLayout tabStrip = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabStrip.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

private void selectFavorite(){

    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db", 
null);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main WHERE fav = 1", 
null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
        String definition = 
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
        String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
        String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
        struct.setWord(word);
        struct.setDefinition(definition);
        struct.setTrans(trans);
        struct.setImg(img);
        struct.setId(id);
        favorite.add(struct);
    }

}

private void selectList(){

    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db", 
null);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
        String definition = 
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
        String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
        String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
        struct.setWord(word);
        struct.setDefinition(definition);
        struct.setTrans(trans);
        struct.setImg(img);
        struct.setId(id);
        list.add(struct);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for some tips about how to track down the cause of the crash.

Comment: I know why it crashes . it tries to copy database before granting permission . I tried to get permission first and then copy database in if clause but it's not helpful

Comment: Requesting permissions is asynchronous. This means that the call does not block and your code will copy the database, as you have seen. Read https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java for an explanation of how to correctly respond to permission granted or denied.

Comment: did u read my code? I used same method. but still I got problem .

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: this is the log:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Comment: any reason why you're copying to the SDCard? if not, then copy it to the ApplicationStorageDirectory && you don't need to worry about the permissions.

Comment: I think I have to change this part
destPath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
but to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple. Move your Copy DB code into permission granted handling. If you do it in your onCreate prior to having permission you will crash. Bets of luck.

package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

```
        import android.Manifest;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
        import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
        import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Gravity;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context context;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageView hamburger;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    String destPath;

    public static ArrayList<Structure> list = new ArrayList<Structure>();
    public static ArrayList<Structure> favorite = new ArrayList<Structure>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){


            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this
                        , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                ,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                        , 1);

            }else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this
                        , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                ,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                        , 1);

            }else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You grandet 
                        earlier",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

        context = getApplicationContext();
        setTabOption();

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        hamburger = findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
        hamburger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
            }
        });







    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                if (grantResults.length >= 2 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   setupDB();
                   setupNavDrawer();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);

            alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

            alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }


    private void setTabOption() {
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                context));
        TabLayout tabStrip = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabStrip.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupDB(){
        try {
            destPath =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
            File file = new File(destPath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();
                CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("md_book.db"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/md_book.db"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void setupNavDrawer(){
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.exit) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);

                    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

                    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
                                        which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
                                        which) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        selectList();
        selectFavorite();
    }

    private void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    private void selectFavorite(){

        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db",
                null);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main WHERE fav = 1",
                null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
            String definition =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
            String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
            String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

            Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
            struct.setWord(word);
            struct.setDefinition(definition);
            struct.setTrans(trans);
            struct.setImg(img);
            struct.setId(id);
            favorite.add(struct);
        }

    }

    private void selectList(){

        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db",
                null);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
            String definition =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
            String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
            String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

            Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
            struct.setWord(word);
            struct.setDefinition(definition);
            struct.setTrans(trans);
            struct.setImg(img);
            struct.setId(id);
            list.add(struct);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to use CopyDB(); in my code but actually my method is CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) and it gives error

Comment: Here I moved your nav and db setup to methods and call from permission granted callback. Try that and see if you are cleared up

Comment: Until you are certain you have permission handled and proper order of accessing it, I would focus on that part. Once you are sure you have permissions "before" trying to move it, if you still have an error, then I will help with the next error you get

Comment: I don't know how to thank you sir. My problem with crash on first run solved . now on first run it doesn't load database

Comment: Crash is gone . Only problem is with database. Now it doesn't show

Comment: can you elaborate a bit, what do you mean by doesn't show? Is it correctly copying it into the file system? you can see it in a file explorer app?

Comment: Yes.Database is copied  successfully. But my list is empty I have no data on screen

Comment: Put a try/catch around your open DB call and the while loop that handles the cursor and see if you are actually opening the DB and getting values back. If you are, then your issue is adapter and ui related, if you are not, then your issues is DB access or location related

Comment: I tried try / catch but it doesn't let me . I'm really desperate.

Comment: Let's move to private messaging, I think we need to discuss logs, and more details about which breakpoints are being hit. Otherwise this will take a lot of time back and forth here ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help.If it's not against this forum's rule can I leave my telegram id or any other way you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure how to move to direct message, but I know if you reply a couple more times it will happen automatically

Comment: my reputation is not enough to chat :( it gives error

Comment: oh maybe that is why it's not popping up haha, wasn't sure. well I don't know what the policy on email is here so I'll leave that at your discretion to find out if it is acceptable to share or not

Comment: I guess there is no problem . this is my telegram id : sam_program

Comment: not sure what telegram id is? also not sure what sam_program does?